# Barcode128 - 3 digit String barcode width is larger than 4 digit string barcode

Tags: java, itext, barcode

I have tried to generate the `Barcode128` barcode to be placed on label and usually labels are less width. I am wondering that `3 digit(100)` String barcode width is larger than `4 digit(1001)` string barcode. `3 digit barcode` should be less than the 4 digit barcode right? I have verified in online barcode generation `3 digit barcode` width is less than the 4 digit barcode width where as iText api takes width more for `3 digit` string compared to `4 digit string`.

Could anybody please let us know the reason for this and how to make `3 digit barcode shorter than the 4 digit barcode?`

Online barcode generator URL [here](https://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/index.php)

[image: 3 digit barcode and 4 digit barcode with iText API]

Code sample used to generate the barcode.

```
Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
    code128.setCode(myText);
    Image myBarCodeImage128 = code128.createImageWithBarcode(contentByte,
        null, null);
```

then image is added to pdf document.

Comment: Can you show us how you generate the barcode?

Comment: Thanks. Barcode image is added

Comment: You are right **your** generated 3 digit barcode is wider then the 4 digit barcode. On the URL you posted the 3 digit barcode is narrower then the 4 digit barcode. But based on what we should give you an answer why it's like it it with your code? If a guess is enough for you: Maybe you do something wrong? The guess is based on the amount of information you have provided.

Comment: It is very direct and code sample was added to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a working snippet based on the answer from Paulo Soares.

```
Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(340, 842));
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, 
    new FileOutputStream("barcodes.pdf"));
document.open();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

document.add(new Paragraph("Barcode 128 demo"));

Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
code128.setCode("100");
code128.setCodeSet(Barcode128CodeSet.B);
document.add(code128.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null));

code128 = new Barcode128();
code128.setCode("1001");
code128.setCodeSet(Barcode128CodeSet.B);
document.add(code128.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null));
document.close();
```

Comment: Thank you example is now showing 3 digit barcode length is not more than the 4 digit barcode. could you please confirm that is there any impact of setting codeSet as B ? i have to generate the barcode not only for numbers but also for alphanumeric characters using the same code.

Comment: @Dhorrairaajj The characterset 'B' in barcode 128 would fulfil the requirement if you are using numbers, and latin charcaters (lower- and uppercase). For a complete list of supported characters in the different modes have a look at this [encoding table](http://www.barcodeisland.com/code128.phtml).

Comment: Help full link to understand the concept. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Barcode 128 has several ways to encode digits. One of the ways is to encode 2 digits in the same symbol. In 4 digit case case you have two symbols each with two digits, two symbols in total. In the 3 digit case you have a symbol for two digits, a symbol to switch to alphanumeric and symbol for the last digit, three symbols in total. As you can see, less is more in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any way to minimize the length of the 3 digit barcode than 4 digit as i can generate the small length 3 digit barcode than 4 digit barcode in [link](https://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/index.php) online

Comment: You can force the code set with setCodeSet(Barcode128CodeSet.B).

Comment: there are 3 code sets (A, B, C) for Code128. Code set C can print 2 numerical characters with a single barcode bar, so Code set C should be used for purely numerical data. In your particular case the problem may be the fact that you only have 3 characters of data in your second example. Encoding 3 digits needs more space because you first need a bar in code C for the first two digits, then a bar to switch to code A or B, then the third digit in code A or B. With 4 digits, you only need two bars in code C and you're done. Code c becomes more economic with larger numbers.

Comment: Thanks paulo, I did not find such code in iText5.2.1.jar, Is it exists in latest jar ?

Comment: Thank you Dirk for detail explanation